# ASP.NET 5 Console Application dnxcore50 missing `System.Net.Http' assembly reference?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am on OS X using visual studio code and am trying to make an HTTP request using System.Net.Http with dnxcore50. When I run `mcs -debug Program.cs` I get the message:

> Program.cs(2,18): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net'. Are you missing 'System.Net.Http' assembly reference?`

Here is my project.json:

```
{
"version": "1.0.0-*",
"description": "Console Application",
"authors": [
    "your name"
],
"tags": [
    ""
],
"projectUrl": "",
"licenseUrl": "",
"dependencies": {
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "7.0.1",
    "System.Net.Http": "4.0.1-beta-23217",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client": "5.2.3"
},
"commands": {
    "ConsoleApplication": "ConsoleApplication"
},
"frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {},
    "dnxcore50": {
        "dependencies": {
            "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23217",
            "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23217",
            "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-23217",
            "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23217",
            "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23217"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This link might give some idea, dnxcore50 has more dependencies related to System.Net.Http. If you can include those it might work. https://www.nuget.org/Packages/system.net.http

Comment: @MithunPattankar I think in the project.lock.json file it specifies all the dependencies, so I shouldn't have to include those.

Comment: Note: `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi` is part of ASP.NET 4 and won't work on ASP.NET 5. Use [`Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/6.0.0-beta8) in stead (MVC 6).

Comment: @HenkMollema according to the [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.webapi.client/) it depends on 4.5, so it will work with ASP.NET 5, but that doesn't have much to do with my question. I also have used `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` in an ASP.NET 5 MVC app, so I'm fairly confident it does work.

Comment: It does, but your app won't compile on DNX Core 5.0 then. I was just pointing out a possible dependency issue. Can you run `dnu restore`?

Comment: @HenkMollema dnu restore works fine, I can even run dnu build.

Answer (score 0):

If you use DNX then you don't call the C# compiler directly. Mcs doesn't know how to compile the new projects. You should use `dnu build` instead:

`dnu build <path to your project.json>`

Comment: I'm following the Mono debugging help from [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_mono-debugging)

Comment: Those instructions are a little outdated and, unfortunately, confusing. They mention ASP.NET but that's not debugging for ASP.NET 5. I'll ping the owners to update them